# Intensify penalization in a NN

Tags: regression, neural-networks, loss-functions

I am using a NN with ConvLSTM2D (in Keras). I am trying to reconstruct a 150 x 150 matrix, so it is a regression problem and I am using `mse` as loss function. Each pixel value is precipitation in 1 hour.

Although there is learning, the values predicted are *very* small; for instance, when it should forecast 10 litres, it outputs 0.01 for that pixel/point. I think part of the problem could be the dataset is full of 0s (nothing strange, since it is precipitation and most days and in most places it doesn't rain), so the penalization with values badly learnt is very weak.

Do you have an idea on how could I intensify the penalization, perhaps using instead of `mse`, something to a greater power, like $\frac{1}{150\cdot 150}\sum_{pixels}(y_{pixels,obs}-y_{pixels,fc})^4$, the fourth power or more. Is there any recommendation in the literature for this? Thx.

Comment: You think about the conditional probability of precipitation to derive a better loss function as well. If it's approximately Gaussian, then MSE (the Gaussian negative log likelihood) is a good loss function. But, if isn't, you'll probably get better results with a more appropriate loss.

Comment: Thx. Precipitation is far from Gaussian, since it is very biased towards 0. It is usually modeled by a Gamma (but there are alternatives). As you said, this could mean that there are better options than MSE (but not sure what of them)...

Comment: One technique is to do a standardization to your data so the scale will be similar and it will be each to learn. i.e. $x_i = \frac {x_i - \mu} {\sigma}$

Comment: Thanks, I am using a `np.log(x+1)/3.0` due to the non gaussian nature of the data. (I read this kind of log transformations are good for biased data), and the division by 3 is the division by the log of maxium values of my data (~20 litres).